# Ubuntu 22.04 Automated installtion preseed to keep installed package

Tags: system-installation, ubiquity

Are the following preseed keys no longer working in 22.04?
d-i pkgsel/include
ubiquity ubiquity/keep-installed

I have installed realmd in Cubic Chroot environemnt but it's being removed during hte installation even though I have this in preseed file.
d-i pkgsel/include string realmd
ubiquity ubiquity/keep-installed string realmd

But it also doesn't work and realmd is removed during the installation phase.
It worked in 20.04.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure none of the `realmd` packages dependencies are explicitly listed for removal with a check mark on the "Packages" page. Use the `apt depends <package name>` command. For example:

```
apt depends realmd
realmd
  Depends: libc6 (>= 2.34)
  Depends: libglib2.0-0 (>= 2.39.1)
  Depends: libkrb5-3 (>= 1.10+dfsg~alpha1)
  Depends: libldap-2.5-0 (>= 2.5.4)
  Depends: libpolkit-gobject-1-0 (>= 0.99)
  Depends: libsystemd0
  Recommends: policykit-1
    policykit-1:i386
```

Then search for these packages on the "Packages" page. Tip: you can click in the "Packages" page and start typing to search through the list quickly.

Also, make sure another package, flagged for removal on the "Packages" page, does not depend `realmd`.

You can identify which packages depend on another package using the `rdepends <package name>` command. For example

```
apt rdepends realmd
realmd
Reverse Depends:
  Suggests: gnome-control-center
  Suggests: gnome-control-center
  Suggests: budgie-control-center
  Suggests: gnome-control-center
  Recommends: ubuntu-mate-desktop
  Recommends: ubuntu-mate-core
  Suggests: budgie-control-center
```

In the above example, all of the listed packages suggest or recommend `realmd`. So (in this example) `realmd` will not be removed if one of these are removed. However, if you see the tag `Depends:`, then `realmd` will also be removed if the package is removed.

Lastly, you may have to also check that `realmd`'s dependencies are not removed when some other package is removed, because this will cause `realmd` to be removed as well. This is a little time intensive, but you would use the `apt rdepends` command on the other packages that `realmd` itself depends on (`libc6`, `libglib2.0-0`, `libkrb5-3`, etc.).